# svn showing invalid data after deleting the data in required files

Tags: svn

I wanted to delete few alarms from Nagios so I had checked out the data files from SVN and deleted the relevant data then checked in back to SVN. I did required restarts to reflect the changes.
But the deleted data is still shown on Nagios.

When I search the data, I see that it's still showing .svn/pristine folder and no where else. (so there's nothing else to delete it) I tried deleting it from .svn/pristine as well but no luck.
Can someone please help in fixing out this issue? Kindly let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: This sounds as if you did everything right and it still is not working. What does "svn stat" show? Maybe the deletion went wrong somehow?

Comment: Hi Argeman, Thank you for responding.
"svn stat" is showing nothing.
Also, when I grep the data in the checked files I find it in ./.svn/pristine path. So, I've commented the required lines and checked in back.
But I still the target alarm on Nagios.
Later, I checked out the svn repository again and I still see the line as uncommented.

Not sure exactly, why is it happening like that